# Editable DIV Add some text at cursor

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, line-breaks

I have added a button to insert some text from a textarea to an editable DIV using this function found on stakoverflow.

```
function insertAtCursor(){
    document.getElementById('myInstance1').focus() ; // DIV with cursor is 'myInstance1' (Editable DIV)
    var sel, range, html;
    var text = document.getElementById('AreaInsert').value ; // Textarea containing the text to add to the myInstance1 DIV
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            range.insertNode( document.createTextNode(text) );
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
}
```

With Internet Explorer using `document.selection.createRange().text` it works fine for line breaks.
With Firefox and Chrome, line breaks of the textarea are not respected, all the text inserted to the editable div from the textarea is on only one line.

How to modify insertAtCursor() to make it works for line breaks with Firefox and Chrome ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest splitting the text up into separate text nodes, replacing the line breaks with `<br>` elements, creating a `DocumentFragment` containing the text and `<br>` nodes and calling `insertNode()` to insert it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/zfggy/

Code:

```
function insertAtCursor(){
    document.getElementById('myInstance1').focus() ; // DIV with cursor is 'myInstance1' (Editable DIV)
    var sel, range;
    var text = document.getElementById('AreaInsert').value ; // Textarea containing the text to add to the myInstance1 DIV
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            var lines = text.replace("\r\n", "\n").split("\n");
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; ++i) {
                if (i > 0) {
                    frag.appendChild( document.createElement("br") );
                }
                frag.appendChild( document.createTextNode(lines[i]) );
            }

            range.insertNode(frag);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        document.selection.createRange().text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a million. Don't know why but I just had to change this line: `var lines = text.replace('\\r\\n', '\\n').split('\\n');`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a more appropriate solution for your problem. For demonstration see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GwdV4/). See also the css property [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

**Java Script:**

```
var button = document.getElementById('insertText');

button.onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('textarea').value;
    document.getElementById('insertHere').innerText = document.getElementById('insertHere').textContent = text 
};
```

To achieve cross browser compatibility, you could also do this:

```
   var isIE = (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > 0);

   if (! isIE) {
      HTMLElement.prototype.__defineGetter__("innerText", 
              function () { return(this.textContent); });
      HTMLElement.prototype.__defineSetter__("innerText", 
              function (txt) { this.textContent = txt; });
   }
```

Comment: It works but it replaces the content of the <DIV>. I need to insert some content where the cursor is `document.getElementById('myInstance1').focus() ;`